# ReGex to remove all characters before the last underscore unless it's attached to a certain word

Tags: regex, filenames

I have a bunch of `png` files. Half of them look like `name_001.png` but the other half has an extra underscore and looks like `name_001_tr.png`.

What I want to do is just remove the name part so I'm thinking of using a `RegEx` that will target only underscores that don't have that "tr" next to them, an remove all the characters before the **underscore**.

Any help is appreciated, this will save me a lot of hassle if I can get something that works. Thanks!

EDIT: Some names have a dash in them.

Comment: Are you on Linux/Unix OS?

Comment: I'm on mac os. Also dustmouse, that seems to nearly do it but I something I forgot to mention- some names have dashes in them. so it's not bothering to change those names. Thanks for being so quick to help, guys! Dustmouse, you may like to submit an answer now as you seem very close to solving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
^[^_]+_
```

https://regex101.com/r/jS5qP8/1

You will need to use a replace function to then replace this with an empty string, depending on what platform you're using.

**UPDATE:** If there is always a series of digits, and that is the start of what you want to capture, you can do this:

```
^\D+_
```

https://regex101.com/r/gJ0vQ6/1

**UPDATE:** This should meet the criteria for the latest requirement:

```
.*?_(?=\d+)|\s*\d+(?=_tr.png)
```

https://regex101.com/r/rV2fV9/1

Comment: Don't forget some names have a dash in them. The current expression seems to ignore names with a dash in them. And yes, I am using Name Mangler which allows me to replace with an empty string.

Comment: So is it supposed to ignore names with dashes?  Because it will grab anything that isn't an underscore up until the first underscore.  Including names with dashes.

Comment: Oops, I jsut realized that is not the problem. There is another underscore in the name. That's why. So some filenames look like name_name_001.png and name_name_001_tr.png

Comment: Is there always a series of digits like 001 that you want to capture?

Comment: Yes but only attached to an underscore. The filenames are a bit confusing though and I tried to simplify a lot of them as I thought it would be easier to make an expression but I suppose not. Here's a better example of the file name:  name_name-16A1P_05 001_tr.png   And I want to keep that 05 and _tr.

Comment: Sorry, yes that's what I want. But that first expression nearly worked. It's just some of the names have that underscore in them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91879/discussion-between-dustmouse-and-shaunxer).